# How to make equation number not lag behind equation?

Tags: equations

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    C_{{DL}_{nacelles}} = \num{1.6231e-4}C_L^3 - \num{2.5826e-4}C_L^2 + \num{1.3698e-4}C_L - \num{2.4217e-5}
\end{equation}
```

It compiles like this:

[image]

How do I make the equation number not lag behind the equation?

Comment: You just want the tag to overwrite the equation? Probably not... what do you suggest should happen?

Comment: You could break the equation at the `+` sign and use two lines. Please provide a full MWE instead of a code snippet so we can help you find a good solution.

Comment: @Werner - While it's true that the OP last month posted a query with exactly the same title as that of the present query, the underlying causes of the typesetting problem would appear to be quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the two suggestions already made in the comments -- let the equation overwrite the equation number (unacceptable!), and introduce a line break -- there are some possibilities afforded by the fact that you're using the `\num` macro of the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to format the coefficients of the variables `C_L^3`, `C_L^2`, and `C_L`.

1. Before proceeding to presenting these possibilities, I'd like you to take a careful look at the expression produced by your code that employs an `equation` environment -- see eq. 1 below -- and a `gather` environment -- see eq. 1' below. It's the *exact same math code* in both equations. Nevertheless, the equation produced by the `equation` environment (couldn't resist the pun, sorry) is typeset much more compactly, to the point where it and its associated equation number *almost* fit side by side.

   The more compact look comes about because LaTeX will reduce the space around operators of type `math-bin` (such as `+`, `-`, and `\times`) *automatically* in single-line equation environments, such as `equation`, in an attempt to make the material fit within the text block. Importantly, LaTeX does *not* apply this optimization for multi-line equation environments, such as `gather` and `align`.
2. Equation 2 introduces an improvement that's modest in terms of space saved, but is welcome in terms of legibility and fine math typography: Change `nacelles` to `\mathrm{nacelles}` (or `\textup{nacelles}`) in the second-level subscript of the variable to the left of the `=` symbol.
3. Equation 3 introduces the option `tight-spacing=true` to the four `\num` directives. This eliminates the whitespace around the four instances of `\times`. The equation's width shrinks noticeably compared to eq. 2.
4. Equation 4 adds the option `exponent-product=\cdot`, which replaces `\times` with `\cdot`. Even though some more space is saved, it's not enough to make the equation *and* the label fit on the same line. Note also that `\cdot` without any whitespace around it looks very cramped; I would therefore *not* recommend using this combination of options.
5. Eq. 5 goes back to using `\times` (while still applying `tight-spacing`), but applies `round-mode` and `round-precision` options to make the numbers display just 3 significant digits. Yay! We've succeeded in our mission! Of course, if there's a compelling reason to show `1.6231` instead of just `1.62`, rounding the numbers would not be permissible. On the other hand, do you really expect your readers to remember for more than a few fleeting seconds that the coefficient was `1.6231`? Wouldn't your readers be served equally well, or arguably even better, if you reported the coefficient to be `1.62`?
6. Having to input lengthy expressions such as

   ```
   \num[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{...}
   ```

   very quickly becomes very tedious and error-prone. If your documents ends up featuring more than a couple of these instructions, you should consider creating a macro, called `\numx` in the example below, as follows:

   ```
    \newcommand\numx[1]{\num[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{#1}}
   ```

   so that you may input the numbers as `\numx{1.6231}`, etc. This is done in eq. 6.

   Eq. 6 contains a further tweak, which doesn't save a lot of space but may be welcome from a fine-typography perspective. The tweak consists of adding `\!` ("negative thinspace") to the four subscript terms of the variable `C`; e.g., `C_{\!L}^3`. Let me stress that the purpose of "snugging up" the `L` subscript to `C` is to avoid creating little "visual holes" between `C` and `L`.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather' environment
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\num' macro
% for use in eq. 6 below:
\newcommand\numx[1]{\num[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Using an \texttt{equation} environment:
\begin{equation}
C_{{DL}_{nacelles}} 
  = \num{1.6231e-4}C_L^3 
  - \num{2.5826e-4}C_L^2 
  + \num{1.3698e-4}C_L
  - \num{2.4217e-5}
\end{equation}

\bigskip\noindent
Using a \texttt{gather} environment:
\begin{gather}
%% eq 1'
C_{{DL}_{nacelles}} 
  = \num{1.6231e-4}C_L^3 
  - \num{2.5826e-4}C_L^2 
  + \num{1.3698e-4}C_L 
  - \num{2.4217e-5} \tag{$1'$}\\
%% eq 2
C_{{\mathit{DL}}_{\textup{nacelles}}} 
  = \num{1.6231e-4}C_L^3 
  - \num{2.5826e-4}C_L^2 
  + \num{1.3698e-4}C_L 
  - \num{2.4217e-5} \\
%% eq 3
C_{{\mathit{DL}}_{\textup{nacelles}}} 
  = \num[tight-spacing=true]{1.6231e-4}C_L^3 
  - \num[tight-spacing=true]{2.5826e-4}C_L^2 
  + \num[tight-spacing=true]{1.3698e-4}C_L 
  - \num[tight-spacing=true]{2.4217e-5} \\
%% eq 4
C_{{\mathit{DL}}_{\textup{nacelles}}} 
  = \num[tight-spacing=true,exponent-product=\cdot]{1.6231e-4}C_L^3 
  - \num[tight-spacing=true,exponent-product=\cdot]{2.5826e-4}C_L^2 
  + \num[tight-spacing=true,exponent-product=\cdot]{1.3698e-4}C_L 
  - \num[tight-spacing=true,exponent-product=\cdot]{2.4217e-5} \\
%% eq 5
C_{{\mathit{DL}}_{\textup{nacelles}}} 
  = \num[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{1.6231e-4}C_L^3 
  - \num[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{2.5826e-4}C_L^2 
  + \num[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{1.3698e-4}C_L 
  - \num[tight-spacing=true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{2.4217e-5} \\
%% eq 6
C_{\!{\mathit{DL}}_{\textup{nacelles}}} 
  = \numx{1.6231e-4}C_{\!L}^3 
  - \numx{2.5826e-4}C_{\!L}^2 
  + \numx{1.3698e-4}C_{\!L} 
  - \numx{2.4217e-5}
\end{gather}
   
\end{document}
```